# Authentication with GCS on GCE with .NET library

Tags: c#, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I have an ASP.NET sample that uses the new Google Cloud .NET library to store some files on GCS. I do "gcloud auth login" to authenticate before running the sample locally. When I deployed this sample to Compute Engine, I thought I had to do setup authentication for the Compute Engine instance as well but it looks like it just works. Requests from Compute Engine to Cloud Storage is authenticated by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a GCE instance and choose to "Allow full access to all Cloud APIs", your credentials are preloaded onto that GCE instance.  No need to copy .json files or run gcloud auth.  Using Application Default Credentials finds and uses the preloaded credentials.

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that your sample is using [Google Application Default Credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials) which tries to take a lot of the work out of writing client authentication code by using ambient information where possible. For local testing, [`gcloud`](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials#toolcloudsdk) can provide the credentials. On [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/) or [Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/), it uses the associated service account. See also [Creating and Enabling Service Accounts for [Google Compute Engine] Instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances).